# Not getting login failure reason (only BadCredential Exception is popped)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Tried various ways to get custom message from spring, if user authentication fails.

*Using*

```
<spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

*XML configuration*

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access='ROLE_FUNCTION' />
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            username-parameter="j_username" 
            password-parameter="j_password" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            />
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />  
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
<authentication-manager>
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="**userDetailsService**">
        <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder"/>
     </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.company.project.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
<beans:bean id="**authenticationFailureHandler**" class="com.company.project.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
<beans:bean name="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

Bean definition excerpt is as below

*Implementation* 
**userDetailsService**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.info("Getting access details for user : {}", username);
        UserDto userDto = null;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean enabled = true;
        try {
            userDto = userService.loginUser(username);
            if (userDto == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            }
            if (Active.Y != userDto.getActive()) {
                enabled = false;  
                throw new BadCredentialsException("User account is inactive");
            }
        } catch (BaseException be) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(be.getMessage().toLowerCase());
        }

        UserContext context = new UserContext();
        context.setLoginId(username);
        context.setName(userDto.getName());
        context.setPrincipleId(userDto.getId());

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = getGrantedAuthorities(userDto);
        String password = getActivePassword(userDto);
        accountNonExpired = isAccountActive(userDto);
        accountNonLocked = isAccountUnlocked(userDto);
        credentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsActive(userDto); 

        return new UserLoginDetails(grantedAuthorities, password, username, accountNonExpired, accountNonLocked, credentialsNonExpired, enabled, context);
    }
}
```

**authenticationSuccessHandler** works fine.

**authenticationFailureHandler**

```
   @Component
    public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
   private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            // execute it when user enters wrong password, i.e loginAttempt ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO: something

        }
        // TODO: how do I send message, if authenticationException.
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?error");
        // clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

To show error message I'm using following line

*JSP*

```
<c:set var="errorMessage" value="${sessionScope[\"SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION\"].message}" />
```

Let me brief the expected messages.

1. If user enters wrong credentials he should get
   "Invalid credentials"
2. If user account is inactive he should get
   "Your account is not active"
3. If user exceeded permissible no. of
   attempt his account will get locked and he will get "Your account is
   locked"

> If my implementation is not correct please let me know what changes should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the AuthenticationFailureHandler, you can  extend the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, it already has a method to save exception.

```
protected final void saveException(HttpServletRequest request, AuthenticationException exception) {
            if (forwardToDestination) {
                request.setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, exception);
            } else {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

                if (session != null || allowSessionCreation) {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, exception);
                }
            }
        }
```

When you save the exception to request or session, then you can get the message.

```
${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
```